# Custom Error pages not showing up on website, but do show up when run in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am setting up a user acceptance site on my GoDaddy server. I have read through a bunch of posts and done multiple things but nothing seems to work. While developing in Visual Studio and running the project, all works fine. On the live server, I do not get the custom error pages. It is running IIS 7.

I have tried using different combinations using httpErrors and CustomErrors in the web.config. Using both and each by itself. I have read that using httpErrors is better to use if you have II7. Below are the two areas of code. I am utilizing an Id to get code and one page to pull all errors. I would like some thoughts on that as well. While other documents say you should use a static page for errors, Using razor pages it seems like a weird idea to me as you would have to create the page outside of the project and then add it to it.

Originally i had these setup as the Index of Error but changed it because i thought that might have been the issue. Turns out not..

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
  <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1"/>
  <error statusCode="404" path="Error/Index/404" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
  <error statusCode="500" path="Error/Index/500" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
</httpErrors>


 <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Oops">
   <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/Oops/404"/>
   <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error/Oops/500"/>
 </customErrors>
```

Controller is simple

```
public ActionResult Oops(int id)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = id;

        return View();
    }
```

I would also note that the URL link for the Error is correct. Even if i go directly to the custom error page Url i get the 404 page but not the custom page. To me if you have a controller that is serving up a view and you give it the information it needs, it should come up.

EDIT -

Also when i use the httpErrors i get this on the page -
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

Is there something on the server that needs toggled on or off?

Answer (score 0):

Did a little digging and found a little more detailed document. Here is what fixed my issue.

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode ="ExecuteURL" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="404"/>
  <error statusCode="404" path="/Error/Oops/404" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
  <remove statusCode="500"/>
  <error statusCode="500" path="/Error/Oops/500" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
</httpErrors>
```

I am using both httpErrors and customErrors. No changes were made with customErrors..